# How to define/access BuildTypes, BuildConfig params & Build variants for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM)?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

All above terms used by Android with different meaning and purpose; how can we do similar on KMM ?

While learning on Kotlin Multiplatform for Mobile, I understood that a common way to define all such build stuff not supported for both Android & iOS.

We can do on Android builds, but how can we handle similar need for iOS builds through Gradle on KMM?

Build Type: Can specify for Android & shared-module; not for iOS

BuildConfig: Can not specify on common gradle block, and thus applicable on Android only

Build Variant: Need to handle it at code level to identify variant as product-flavour/similar things are not supported for iOS.

Also, can not access BuildConfig.* fields into commonMain & iOsMain, is there any way to access it?

Any good way to handle such things?

Comment: [BuildKonfig](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig)